# python regular expression to match strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse a string, such as:

```
package: name='jp.tjkapp.droid1lwp' versionCode='2' versionName='1.1'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
```

I want to get:

```
string1: jp.tjkapp.droidllwp`

string2: 1.1
```

Because there are multiple uses-permission, I want to get permission as a list, contains:
`WRITE_APN_SETTINGS`, `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.

Could you help me write the python regular expression to get the strings I want?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that entire code block one giant string?

Comment: Did you write any Regex already?

Comment: You could consider it as a giant string in a text file, but you can retrieve line-by-line from the file.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im wrote some re already, but need some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code block you provided is one long string, here stored in a variable called `input_string`:

```py
name = re.search(r"(?<=name\=\')[\w\.]+?(?=\')", input_string).group(0)
versionName = re.search(r"(?<=versionName\=\')\d+?\.\d+?(?=\')", input_string).group(0)
permissions = re.findall(r'(?<=android\.permission\.)[A-Z_]+(?=\')', input_string)
```

Explanation:

#### name

- `(?<=name\=\')`: check *ahead* of the main string in order to return only strings that are preceded by `name='`.  The `\` in front of `=` and `'` serve to escape them so that the regex knows we're talking about the `=` string and not a regex command.  `name='` is **not** also returned when we get the result, we just know that the results we get are all preceded by it.
- `[\w\.]+?`: This is the main string we're searching for. `\w` means any alphanumeric character and underscore.  `\.` is an escaped period, so the regex knows we mean `.` and not the regex command represented by an unescaped period.  Putting these in `[]` means we're okay with anything we've stuck in brackets, so we're saying that we'll accept any alphanumeric character, `_`, or `.`.  `+` afterwords means *at least one of the previous thing*, meaning at least one (but possibly more) of `[\w\.]`.  Finally, the `?` means *don't be greedy*--we're telling the regex to get the smallest possible group that meets these specifications, since `+` could go on for an unlimited number of repeats of anything matched by `[\w\.]`.
- `(?=\')`: check *behind* the main string in order to return only strings that are followed by `'`.  The `\` is also an escape, since otherwise regex or Python's string execution might misinterpret `'`.  This final `'` is **not** returned with our results, we just know that in the original string, it followed any result we do end up getting.

Comment: Could you tell me what does (?<= and ?(?=\') mean?

Comment: You should really read the [`re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind assertion, it checks whether the string your searching for is preceded by another string, but doesn't actually return that string as part of the match afterwards.  `(?=...)` is a lookbehind assertion, which ensures that you get back only strings that have the specified string *after* them, but also doesn't return the lookbehind string as part of the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regex by reading the file content line by line.

```
>>> def split_string(s):
...     if s.startswith('package'):
...             return [i.split('=')[1] for i in s.split() if "=" in i]
...     elif s.startswith('uses-permission'):
...             return s.split('.')[-1]
... 
>>> split_string("package: name='jp.tjkapp.droid1lwp' versionCode='2' versionName='1.1'")
["'jp.tjkapp.droid1lwp'", "'2'", "'1.1'"]
>>> split_string("uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS'")
"WRITE_APN_SETTINGS'"
>>> split_string("uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'")
"RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'"
>>> split_string("uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'")
"ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'"
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
inputFile = open("test.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in inputFile:
    if line.startswith("package"):
        words = line.split()
        string1 = words[1].split("=")[1].replace("'","")
        string2 = words[3].split("=")[1].replace("'","")
```

test.txt file contains input data you mentioned earlier..